# rename folders with batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to rename a ton of photo folders from Eg: Summer Vacation (1970) blah blah
to Summer Vacation (1970)
so the names need to be shortened back to the )

The solution I found works ok, till I remove the echo and then I get syntax error.

```
@Echo off
Cd /D "C:\Temp"
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
'Dir /B/S/O-N/AD "*(*)*"'
) Do For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%B in ( "%%A"
) Do Echo Ren "%%~A" "%%B(%%C)"
```

Comment: *and then I get syntax error* is a meaningless problem description. What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I would assume it is because you are using the `Ren`ame command incorrectly. The rename command expects a name only as the second argument, not a full path. In order to do that, you'd need to change the result variable from the outer for loop to expand to its name and/or name and extension within the inner for loop. Example: `@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "C:\Temp\*(*)*" /A:D /B /O:-N /S 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Delims=)" %%H In ("%%~nxG") Do @Ren "%%G" "%%H)"`

Comment: the error msg is "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: Thanks @Compo that done the trick nicely.